# How to use jQuery UI draggable helper function to display duplicate image with an added class

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

The code I'm currently trying to debug:

```
$('#bottom').children().draggable({
   helper: function () {
      console.log($(this).attr("src"));
      return  $("<img src'" + $(this).attr("src") + "' 
                  height='100' width='78' class='green-box-shadow'>");                        
   }
});
```

this code adds a box shadow and the console logs out the src to the current image in which I am dragging, but for some reason does not actually render out an image... just a "green box shadow with no image".

Any help is appreciated, I've hit a wall, thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You missed `=` after src, use it like,

```
$("<img src='" + $(this).attr("src") + "' height='100' width='78' class='green-box-shadow'>");
```

Even there is no need of jquery, you can use `this.src` for images like,

```
$("<img src='" +this.src+ "' height='100' width='78' class='green-box-shadow'>");
```

Comment: Its been a long day... Thank you